# LinearLayout not resizing for dynamic content

Tags: android, android-layout

I am able to add TextViews programmatically to a LinearLayout however the text writes over the TextView below it. I'm not sure how to make my LinearLayout expand to include the new content? This is the relevant part of my XML which is inside a RelativeLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_header"
    android:id="@+id/item_features"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_description_header"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_features"
    android:text="Item Description" />
```

My code is below. mFeatureArea is the LinearLayout:

```
for (String item: spot.getFeatures()){
    TextView feature = new TextView(this);
    feature.setText(item);
    mFeatureArea.addView(feature);
}
```

However all I get is the features layered on top of my item description header. After some Googling I tried calling .requestLayout on both the LinearLayout as well as the main RelativeLayout, but that didn't fix the issue?

Comment: could you show us how you define `mFeatureArea`?

Comment: mFeatureArea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_features); this is done in the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

What is the parent component of The mFeaturArea-LineraLayout?
 It appears it is either a FramewLayout or a RelativeLayout both will be overlapped. Check respective parent component properties and set the parameters properly to adjust the alignments.

Comment: The parent component for the LinearLayout is the RelativeLayout which is the main node of the activity. So both [item_description_header] and [item_features] have the same parent. What setting should I be adjusting?